# Angular2 (hybrid mode) can't Downgrade Directive to NG1 (ES5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular

My problem Is that I'm trying to create an Angular2 attribute directive in ES5 while still in hybrid mode (using [UpgradeAdapter](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/upgrade/index/UpgradeAdapter-class.html)). So all Angular2 code is being converted down to NG1.This is done by utilizing UpgradeAdapter's 'downgradeNG2Component' function, but since I'm creating a Directive and not a Component I need to use a 'downgradeNG2Directive function', although it doesn't exist.

*But can't you just code it in NG1?* -> No I'm porting from angular 1 to 2 and need the code itself to be Angular2

The directive is just a simple autoFocus directive that focuses an element whenever "li-common-auto-focus" is an attribute.

TLDR: I'm wondering if there is a way to convert an Angular2 attribute directive down to NG1 using upgradeAdapter?

Here is the code:

AutoFocus.js

```
//<example>
//   <file name="index.html">
//     <input class="type-text" type="text" li-common-auto-focus>
//   </file>
// </example>


var autoFocusModule = angular.module('li.directives.common.auto-focus', []);
var liCommonAutoFocus = ng.core
    .Directive({
      selector:"li-common-auto-focus",
      inputs:["ignoreMe"]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor:[ng.core.ElementRef, function(eltRef){
        console.log(eltRef);
        console.log(eltRef.nativeElement);
      }],
      ngAfterViewInit:function(){

      }
 });

autoFocusModule.directive(OBJ.Angular.upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(liCommonAutoFocus));
```

init.js

```
var OBJ = {
  Angular: {
    upgradeAdapter: new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter()
  }
};
```

bootstrap.js

```
OBJ.Angular.upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['li.directives.common.auto-focus']);
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/Rx.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>Testing</div>
    <input class="type-text" size="50px" type="text" placeholder="">
    <input class="type-text" size="50px" type="text" placeholder="Should Focus ME" li-common-auto-focus>
    <input class="type-text" size="50px" type="text" placeholder="">


    <script src="init.js"></script>
    <script src="auto-focus.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the UpgradeAdapter code, you could not downgrade an attribute directive. 
When you downgrade a component the constructed directive have 
`restrict: 'E',`
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f92591054bd4c45026939bcd49fd7e49c32db28a/packages/upgrade/src/common/downgrade_component.ts#L70

An alternative approach is to upgrade the directive refer to the upgrade guide on upgrading a directive.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-angularjs-component-directives-from-angular-code

Another alternative is to have two versions (NG1 and NG 2) of the same directive side by side, until you have upgrade all the consumer of NG1 version.